# is it ok to wrap similarly connected components in the same HoC instead of having them all connect() the same way to the auth reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

A few of my components are only connected to the auth reducer, for the only reason that they need to know if the user is authenticated/logged or not. 
I created an higher order component (withAuth) to wrap those components (and add the isLogged prop), but I do not know if it is a good pattern or not.

ps - the described use case was simplified, there are a couple more properties/actions mapped that way.

Thanks for the help!

Edit - here is some code to illustrate: let's pretend we have a few widgets sharing that code (add a few mapped actions, props, etc)

```javascript
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getIsLogged } from 'authManager/reducer'

const Widget1 = props => {
  return <div>{props.isLogged ? 'yay!' : 'nope'}</div>
}

Widget1.propTypes = {
  isLogged: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isLogged: getIsLogged(state)
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(Widget1)
```

I just refactored creating the following HoC

```javascript
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getIsLogged, getFirstName } from 'authManager/reducer'

const withAuth = ComposedComponent => {
  class _hoc extends React.Component {
    render () {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }

  _hoc.propTypes = {
    isLogged: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    firstName: PropTypes.string
  }

  const mapStateToProps = (state, {params}) => {
    return {
      isLogged: getIsLogged(state),
      firstName: getFirstName(state)
    }
  }

  return connect(
    mapStateToProps
  )(_hoc)
}

export default withAuth
```

And now all the previous widgets look like this:

```javascript
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import withAuth from 'hoc/withAuth'

const Widget1 = props => {
  return <div>{props.isLogged ? 'yay!' : 'nope'}</div>
}

Widget1.propTypes = {
  isLogged: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}

export default withAuth(Widget1)
```

I start wondering if there is something I am doing wrong with connected component/containers, and that what that HoC should be (or is?).

Anyway, the question stands: is that a good move or not?

Comment: Do you have some code to illustrate? Generally, wrapping components in HOCs is the way to go.

Comment: @Lee, here is the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is totally fine. The idiomatic way to connect your  component is to connect those that are the most "closer" to the data they need.
Creating a HoC `withAuth` is definitively a good way to go. You don't have to worry to much about the number of connected components in your app since the complexity for the pub/sub pattern is O(n) with `n` the number of connected components. Since it's very  unlikely you have thousands of them, dealing with many HoC that connect to the store isn't too much of a big deal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! do you consider a component that is wrapped into `withAuth` connected/smart/container, or presentational/dumb?

Comment: The `withAuth` component I'm referring to is the one you mentioned above, so it's a connected/smart/container.